# GUI tool for MongoDB in Ubuntu server

Tags: gui, ubuntu, server, mongodb

We use a Ubuntu server to host a mean-stack application. Normally, we connect with the server by ssh. We realise that there are a lot of manipulation and modification around the MongoDB database. So is there any existing GUI tool to simplify the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Robomongo https://robomongo.org/download it has a wide variety of options and simple user friendly gui

Answer (score 0):

http://genghisapp.com/ 
 The single-file MongoDB admin app

is a nice gui in several ways of instalation I use php

cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/genghis.conf

```
Alias /genghis /home/sergio/genghis
<Directory /home/sergio/genghis>
    DirectoryIndex genghis.php
    Require all granted
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /genghis
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule (.*) genghis.php/$1 [L,QSA]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can it be used in a ubuntu server that we connect with by ssh?